# Who did Matt Smith play in Rise of Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

Has anyone any info on the character Matt Smith was meant to be playing in *Rise of Skywalker*? Or was it just a red herring?

Comment: Unfortunately, no one

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe - Given his appalling performance in Terminator Genysysis, it's probably for the best

Comment: @Valorum Never seen it, but I loved him in Doctor Who

Answer (score 6):

It was [announced in Variety](https://variety.com/2018/film/news/star-wars-episode-ix-matt-smith-1202886507/) in August 2018 that he was attached to the film but this exclusive was accredited to "[unnamed] sources"*. From that point onward, there were no official confirmations that he was going to be in it aside from a [quickly deleted tweet from Disney](https://thedoctorwhocompanion.com/2019/05/01/it-looks-like-matt-smith-is-in-star-wars-the-rise-of-skywalker-after-all/), and Smith actively denied it in multiple interviews.

> **Emily Zemler** One takeaway: Matt Smith is not in the next #StarWars movie, despite reports to the contrary. He told me, "*As far as I can tell, I’m definitely not.*" (Although maybe we'll be surprised by his secret keeping in December.)
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/emilyzemler/status/1103644330340818944) - Mar 7, 2019</sup></sub>

There's no indication that he was ever attached to the film and his total absence from the final cut would seem to be proof-positive that the Variety "exclusive" was just speculation.